# ¿Cómo subir una imagen con JavaScript y PHP sin ningún tipo de FrameWork?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario hecho con HTML donde se sube una imagen.
Así tengo el formulario

```
<div class="form" align="center">
  <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input type="text" id="controlNumber" placeholder="Control Number">
  <input type="file" id="studentId" placeholder="Student Id">
  <input type="text" id="payAccount" placeholder="Pay Account">

<h2>Login information</h2>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
<div class="formbuttons">
    <button class="ok" onclick="postPassenger()">Register</button>
</div>
<label id="message"></label>
```

Y así lo mando al archivo PHP

```
function postPassenger()
{
    console.log('POSTING passenger...');
    //create request
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //prepare request
    x.open('POST', 'apis/studentinsert.php', true);
    //form data
    var fd = new FormData();
    //values
    fd.append('lastName', document.getElementById('lastname').value);
    fd.append('name', document.getElementById('firstname').value);
    fd.append('controlNumber', document.getElementById('controlNumber').value);
   //fd.append('studentId', document.getElementById('studentId').value);
    fd.append('payAccount', document.getElementById('payAccount').value);

    console.log(fd);
    //send
    x.send(fd);
    console.log(fd);
    //handle readyState change event
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // check status
        // status : 200=OK, 404=Page not found, 500=server denied access
        // readyState : 4=Back with data
        if (x.status == 200 && x.readyState == 4)
        {
            var JSONdata = JSON.parse(x.responseText); console.log(JSONdata);

        }
    }
}
```

Estuve buscando pero solo aparecen resultados hechos con JQuery o otros FrameWorks no se si sepan alguna alternativa hecha con solo JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma es hacerlo sin `Javascript`:

Ponga sus `input` dentro de un `form`, agregandole a la etiqueta `form` los siguientes atributos:

```
action="upload.php"   <!--para definir a que `PHP` enviar los datos-->
method="post"         <!--El método para enviar los datos-->
enctype="multipart/form-data"   <!--Esto para poder enviar archivos-->
```

Quedaría así:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
   <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
   <input type="text" id="controlNumber" placeholder="Control Number">
   <input type="file" id="studentId" placeholder="Student Id">
   <input type="text" id="payAccount" placeholder="Pay Account">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

En `PHP` los obtiene así:

*Los textos o cadenas

`$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];` el texto dentro del corche de `$_POST[]` sera el `name` o el `id` del `input`

*Los archivos

`$fileImg = $_FILES['studentId']['tmp_name'];` el texto dentro del primer corche de `$_FILES[]` sera el `name` o el `id` del `input`

Final mente para subir el archivo o imagen puede usar esto:

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($fileImg, 'ruta en donde se guardara')) {
    /*aqui puede especificar que hacer en caso de que no cargue el archivo*/
}
```

Tenga en cuenta que este método trabaja recargando la pagina completa, si no quiere recargar la pagina, consulte sobre `AJAX` y le recomiendo usar `JQuery`

Answer (score 0):

La forma de añadir el fichero al FormData es la siguiente (basado en el código expuesto en la pregunta:

```
//asumo que hay un fichero en el input
let file= document.getElementById('studentId').files[0];
fd.append('nombre',file, file.name); //el nombre del fichero es opcional
```

El resto del código es tal cual lo tienes.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Si estás trabajando con formularios te recomiendo utilizar la etiqueta `form` ya que para eso fue creada. Tu código quedaría así:

```
<form id="miFormulario">
    
<div class="form" align="center">
   <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
   <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
   <input type="text" id="controlNumber" placeholder="Control Number">
   <input type="file" id="studentId" placeholder="Student Id">
   <input type="text" id="payAccount" placeholder="Pay Account">
    
    <h2>Login information</h2>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <div class="formbuttons">
   <button class="ok">
     Register
   </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

2.- Te aconsejo no utilizar los eventos directamente en las etiquetas HTML.

De lado de Javascript quedaría algo como esto

```
//Accedemos al formulario

const formulario = document.querySelector('#miFormulario');

// Creamos un objeto FormData y le pasamos como parámetro el formulario

const datosForm = new FormData(formulario);
```

3.- La forma más facil de mandar información de manera asíncrona es **fetch**

```
fetch('tuPHP',{
 method: 'POST',
 body: datosForm
})
```

4.- **fetch** está recibiendo como parámetros la URL a dónde realizas el proceso de registro, el método por el cual estás realizando la petición y por ultimo los datos que vas a mandar en la petición.

4.- Ya por último los recibes con PHP.